# How to build a slack bot to have multiple conversations?

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack

I am building a slack bot using a third party service to handle responses based on inputs rather than just hard coding them into the bot. This service's API needs a client id & a conversation id to get the response. I found out that each time a slack bot receives a message, it creates a new message object each time so there isn't a way of keeping the clientID and conversation ID within the message object and have slack hold onto it.

```
rtm.on(RTM_EVENTS.MESSAGE, function(message // <-- new object each time the bot hears a message){
  rtm.sendMessage('hello', message.channel);
});
```

So shortened down, does anyone know of a way to keep a conversation between a single user and the bot while holding onto some type of variable to hold the client and conversation ID?

Comment: You can spin an app that will receive incoming messages using RTM. Then in that app, you would have a database where you'd keep `conversation_id` and `client_id` and query your db before calling the third-party API. Am I following your goal so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the message.user ID and track the conversation referring to that specific user. You will need to keep track of all ongoing conversations yourself. Something like this

```
rtm.on(RTM_EVENTS.MESSAGE, function(message // <-- new object each time the bot hears a message){
  if(stored_conversations.indexOf(message.user) > -1){
    //customize message depending on history
    rtm.sendMessage('I remember you', message.channel);
  }
});
```

Or, you could use [Botkit](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit) - it manages bot-user conversations for you.

Comment: Sorry for getting back late to you, what is the stored_conversations object? And I was considering using botkit, but for the project i am building it with, it is sort of tricky to work around it.

Comment: stored_conversations is an object (here an undefined array) that you'd have to create in order to store current conversations